# Alert about record has been modified after save it

Tags: python, erp, tryton

I have already saved the record but when I switch from form view to list view, an alert says: **This record has been modified do you want to save it**

I am running tryton version 3.2.

Comment: but why is it asking again and again? I have already saved the record!

Comment: You'd better post some screenshots or something like that to help us understand your problem.

Comment: It seems that your problem is related to https://bugs.tryton.org/issue4026 Do you have any float_time field in the view?

Comment: yes, it is the float_time field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this has been fixed in trunk version (3.5) and will be released on next version 3.6 by the end of April. All the history is found on [bugs.tryton.org/issue4026](https://bugs.tryton.org/issue4026)